# Outlook calendar Invite updates on sharepoint calendar not sending or updating correctly

Tags: calendar

so we have a sharepoint 2013 server configured with email services to be able to create sharepoint only calendar accounts to invite a sharepoint calendar to a meeting.

everything works, but once in a while, when sending or updating an event (from outlook) 
sharepoint would fail to update the meeting in different ways :

- it will either create a whole new event and keep a copy of the previos date
- create a new empty event with "no title" on the date the users tried to invite the calendar

after this happens there's no way to fix the invite in sharepoint, we delete the event, re invite the sharepoint calendar but it keeps failing, the only solution is to create a new event.

Any ideas what could be causing this ?